# AttentionDecoderRNN without MAX_LENGTH

Tags: recurrent-neural-network, pytorch, machine-translation, sequence-to-sequence, attention-model

From the PyTorch Seq2Seq tutorial, http://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/seq2seq_translation_tutorial.html#attention-decoder

We see that the attention mechanism is heavily reliant on the `MAX_LENGTH` parameter to determine the output dimensions of the `attn -> attn_softmax -> attn_weights`, i.e.

```python
class AttnDecoderRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, output_size, dropout_p=0.1, max_length=MAX_LENGTH):
        super(AttnDecoderRNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.dropout_p = dropout_p
        self.max_length = max_length

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(self.output_size, self.hidden_size)
        self.attn = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size * 2, self.max_length)
        self.attn_combine = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size * 2, self.hidden_size)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(self.dropout_p)
        self.gru = nn.GRU(self.hidden_size, self.hidden_size)
        self.out = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.output_size)
```

More specifically

```python
self.attn = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size * 2, self.max_length)
```

I understand that the `MAX_LENGTH` variable is the mechanism to reduce the no. of parameters that needs to be trained in the `AttentionDecoderRNN`.

If we don't have a `MAX_LENGTH` pre-determined. **What values should we initialize the `attn` layer with?**

**Would it be the `output_size`?** If so, then that'll be learning the attention with respect to the full vocabulary in the target language. Isn't that the real intention of the Bahdanau (2015) attention paper?

Comment: Also asked on https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/attentiondecoderrnn-without-max-length/13473

Comment: Did you consider local attention instead of global?

Comment: Not yet but if it's global, there must be some sort of a max? It's just for tractability no? Theoretically, it can do attention for all source words to all target words, right? It's just that if max_length = no. of target words, for the sentence pair any words that doesn't exist in the source will have zeros.

Answer (score 5):

Attention modulates the input to the decoder. That is attention modulates the encoded sequence which is of the same length as the input sequence. Thus, `MAX_LENGTH` should be the maximum sequence length of all your input sequences.